# Minecraft appears to crash my PC

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Whenever I run Minecraft on Linux it causes the entire PC to crash after a few minutes.

I have tried different versions of Java for the same result. Forced power cycle is the only way to recover as the graphics shut down.

Has anyone else had this problem? Is there anything I can do to try and trace the cause of the error?

My Minecraft copy is vanilla with the default resource pack.

Comment: Have you tried to download everything again? Or a live cd? It could be that your graphics card it's just failing or minecraft provokes a fail, could be that you run out of memory, etc. Can you switch to the TTY's with Ctrl+Alt+F1 and check the logs? `dmesg`, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` would be the first places to look.

Comment: We will need a log first before we can help you.

Comment: Your computer could be overheating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment posted by Timtech got me thinking. So I pulled the case open and removed the big thick layer of dust.

Minecraft does seem to tax the hell out of the GPU but I can now run Minecraft for a limited amount of time. So the answer seems to be a hardware issue not as it so very much seemed a software one.

The problem appears to be that I don't use my GPU enough and should play more games.